# S3.upload not working in production environment but working in localhost NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, netlify

I enjoy using AWS but i cant seem to get any of my app's to upload to my bucket in production using nodejs but in localhost development it seems to work flawlessly no issues ever. My apps are hosted on netlify in production.

The issue is in production the callback never gets fired i see the logs in my netlify server such as the "this is the image metadeta" log and for everything else firing besides the callback.

Does anyone know why this issue would only be happening in production? i have all my bucket policy/user roles set to allowing all access with "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy

also my role policies

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
           "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": "s3:*",
           "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket
              "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/testbucket"
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

This is my code for uploading images to my bucket uploadProfilePicToS3 function

```
function uploadProfilePicToS3(file) {
let s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
 accessKeyId: IAM_USER_KEY,
 secretAccessKey: IAM_USER_SECRET,
 Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
});
s3bucket.createBucket(function () {
 var params = {
   Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
   Key: `instacloneprofilepics/${file.name}`,
   Body: file.data,
   ACL: "public-read",
   ContentType: file.mimetype,
 };
 console.log("this is the image metadeta", params);
 s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
     console.log("error in callback");
     console.log(err);
     return;
   }

   console.log("POST UPLOADED SUCCESS FROM CALLBACK");

   console.log(data);
   return data;
 });
});
}
```

then i simply just call the function in my route with the data/file i send from the front end.

```
   const file = req.files.img;

   busboy.on("finish", function () {
     console.log("Upload finished");

     console.log(file);
     uploadProfilePicToS3(file);
   });

   req.pipe(busboy);
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: im not getting an error its just not uploading to the bucket for some reason. Below in the route i just have some queries to my DB and thats working fine as well the s3bucket.upload callback just isnt being fired in production.

Comment: In console open all and see error might be there.

Comment: the only error thats in there is this warning ```ERROR (node:8) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.``` i changed every single new Buffer to Buffer.from and i still get it but i dont know if thats impacting my upload function.

Comment: are you sure you want to create a new bucket (with [`createBucket`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createBucket-property)) for each upload? you should simply upload to an existing bucket... I never used `busboy`, I use [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) instead and I have several apps that I upload files and copy files in S3 ... let me know if you need the code. remove the `s3bucket.createBucket(` line and use `putObject` instead `upload`, all should work fine...

Comment: it doesnt actually create a new bucket it checks to see if there is a bucket already with that name i pass it and if there is it just adds the file to the folder in that bucket i specify. I've also read alot that you should be using upload instead of put0bject and that still wouldnt answer why my code works locally but on in production. Also ill take a look at your code if you send it to me or something this is just the way i learned how to do it.

Comment: @balexandre i changed it to putObject and took out the createBucket and it still didnt work in prod but worked in local.

Comment: @Hunterdev should be also `process.env.IAM_USER_KEY` and `process.env.IAM_USER_SECRET` so you can have those as environment variables in your hosting server ... you're probably getting "Can't authenticate" error ... [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) will help you loading those locally

Comment: @balexandre ive chaged everyone to .env and put my variables on my netlify sever but my callback still doesnt go through when i try to make a post on production.

Comment: @Hunterdev a full example is in Netlify: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/11/17/serverless-file-uploads/

Comment: did you ever find a fix? getting the exact same problem.